# HTML redirect on Page-click

Tags: javascript, html, css

My question is pretty simple but I'm new to HTML. How can I to redirect the User to a new Tab when he is clicking on something on the page itself? I'm trying to put ads on my page and when I use a simple JavaScript popup, they get automatically blocked by the browser.

Hope someone can help!

Comment: Please share a working example of what you have tried so we can assist.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a new tab to open in HTML, use:

```
<a href="destination url" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" > link text </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the body tag via JavaScript and add a `click` event listener.

The you can use `window.open` to redirect the user.

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
document.onclick = myFunction;


function myFunction() {
  window.location.assign("google.com")
}
```

Write the webpage inside the assign function